# Prolog indexOf function

Tags: algorithm, prolog

I have following code snippet. `indexOf()` finds index of given element in list.

There is two problems:

- this function does not work if given element is not first or if it is not in list(`user directive problem`);
- how to modify this function to save index into variable;

```
indexOf([Element|_], Element, 0).
indexOf([], _, -1).

indexOf([_|Tail], Element, Index):-
    indexOf(Tail, Element, Index1),
    Index is Index1 + 1.

:- 
    initialization(main).

main :- 
    indexOf([1, 2, 3], 2, 0).
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not correct. `Index is Index1 + 1` works only if both values are not equal to -1, but you produce -1 for the empty list. Thus `indexOf([1], 2, 0)` would be true in your case.

The line `indexOf([], _, -1).` is the culprit. I don't think it is actually needed at all, since it simply represents an absent result. This would be more appropriate:

```
indexOf([], _, _) :- !, false.
```

Meaning nothing can be found in an empty list (and don't try to satisfy it in any other way). If you *really* want to produce -1, wrap it in another rule and first try to satisfy the original rules, then produce -1 if everything else fails.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody needs a solution, here is my realization:

```
indexOf(Value, [Element|Tail], Cur_index, Index) :-
    Value = Element, Index is Cur_index;
    New_index is Cur_index + 1,
    indexOf(Value, Tail, New_index, Index).

indexOf(Value, List, Index) :-
    indexOf(Value, List, 0, Index);
    Index = -1.
```

Also, you can add version, which returns false, if element is not in list.